# add UIPagerControl inside a UITableViewCell's imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2, uipagecontrol

inside my tableView's Cell i have a ImageView and there i wanna insert a UIPageControll so that i can add multiple images in my ImageView and scroll through it like this :

[image]

this is what i tried (and got stuck ) :

tableViewCell:

```
class EventsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet var coverView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var pageController: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!

    let swipeGestureLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    let swipeGestureRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
...................... ........... 
...........
}
```

TableView:

```
 ///// inside cellforRowAtIndexPath

........

    PagerController = cell.pageController
    swipeGestureLeft = cell.swipeGestureLeft
    swipeGestureRight = cell.swipeGestureRight
    coverView = cell.coverView

    // set gesture direction
    self.swipeGestureLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.swipeGestureRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    // add gesture in to view

    coverView.addGestureRecognizer(self.swipeGestureLeft)
    coverView.addGestureRecognizer(self.swipeGestureRight)

    // add gesture target
    self.swipeGestureLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipeLeft(_:)))
    self.swipeGestureRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipeRight(_:)))

.
.
.
.
.
.

    // functions for recognising the Gestures
func handleSwipeLeft(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if self.PagerController.currentPage != 2 {

          print("left :\(self.PagerController.currentPage) ")

        self.PagerController.currentPage += 1


        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "cover\(self.PagerController.currentPage)")
    }
}

// 
func handleSwipeRight(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    if self.PagerController.currentPage != 0 {

        print("right  :\(self.PagerController.currentPage)")

        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "cover\(self.PagerController.currentPage)")

        self.PagerController.currentPage -= 1
    }


}
```

you can see that am able to recognise the gesture over my `coverView` which is an UIView covering the ImageView and am also able to call this functions but  now how am gonna change the image ?? any clue or guidance will be so helpful for me

P.s if my question is not clear enough then please let me know i'll add some details

Comment: You want the imagView Object that user just swipe. Right?

Comment: yes , change image on swipe @NiravDoctorwala

Comment: Inside your gesture method write this let imageVIew = gesture.view as! UIImageView

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala this is weird , my ImageView is not recognising the gestures

Comment: Please try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your cellForRowAt index add this code

```
cell.imgView.userInteractionEnable = true
cell.imgView.addGestureRecognizer(self.swipeGestureLeft)
cell.imgView.addGestureRecognizer(self.swipeGestureRight)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: well its doing what i ask for , but not as expected its changing the images with glitch (sudden )  effect, i have to use the UIPageControllers , btw thanks , appreciate your effort